# changing layout color android app

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, background

i am trying to write a program that changes the background color of the screen to the color that i decided.
i wrote something like that but when it runs it crashes
what is sthe problem,please help me.here is the xml code

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"


        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Red"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Green" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Blue" />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="White" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the .java code

```
package com.example.flashlight;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class FlashLight extends Activity {

Button red,green,blue,white;
LinearLayout view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash_light);
    red=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    green=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    blue=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    white=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_flash_light, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not assigning the `view` variable to anything, that is probably causing a `NullPointerException` in your code

try adding in your XML file this line under the `LinearLayout`:

`android:id="@+id/view"`

and adding this line to your `onCreate`:

`view = (LinearLayout)findViewBiId(R.id.view);`

Comment: i did what you said and it changed only the button's line not the hall background.

Comment: you need to add the `android:id=@+id/view` to the base layout, that means the one that covers all of the background

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign an id to your `LinearLayout`

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

then initialize your view

```
view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view)
red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    }
});
```

Comment: i did what you said and it changed only the button's line not the hall background.did i do something wrong in the assigning button i mean wrap content or something

Comment: trying changing the height of this `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

This will work for me...
In youyr xml file set id for your Linear Layout as a view.

```
<LinearLayout 

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"


    >
```

In Your java file your linear layout view is null because of id.

so put below line in your java file

```
 view  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);
```

This will work for me....

Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

After onClick use this below code:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

Example:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY); //Add any color you want
    }
```